# Finding maximum value of each element of sublists

Tags: python, list

Suppose

```
a=[[12.935,100],[10.923,184],[04.87,119]]
```

I need to find the minimum and maximum of a[i][1] as in maximum of the second element of the sublists

Comment: Maximum must be 184 and minimum must be 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as simple as that:

```
a = [[12.935, 100], [10.923, 184], [04.87, 119]]

mn = min(i[1] for i in a)  # 100
mx = max(i[1] for i in a)  # 184
```

using the built-in [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) for the second items `i[1]` in your list `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
In [5]: min(a, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
Out[5]: 100

In [6]: max(a, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
Out[6]: 184
```